# How do I print an NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSBitmapImageRep and I need to print it.  Do I need to put ii in an NSView somehow before printing or is there some way to print it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `NSView` is the quick and easy way. see also: `-[NSBitmapImageRep CGImage]`.

An alternative would be to use PrintCore.framework, part of ApplicationServices.framework.

Comment: I edited the question to include details about my attempt to use NSImageView, which didn't work.  Is there some way to use NSView directly?

Comment: Actually, the NSImageView should work fine, the problem I had was with the NSBitMapImageRep, not my printing code.